# Not receiving parity error using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, serial-port, win-universal-app

I am currently developing an application for a raspberry pi that utilizes serial communications. The application is a Windows Universal App using the Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication library. The data it will be receiving will toggle between the parity bit being on and off under certain conditions. As of now, I have subscribed to the ErrorReceived event, with the parity set to Space. Even though I am receiving data transmitted with the Parity bit on (Mark), the ErrorReceived event is not firing. Just to confirm, I made a small console app that utilized the NET2.0 System.IO.Ports library class and subscribed to the same ErrorReceived event, and I consistently receiving the error event. Is this a limitation of the hardware I am using, or is there something else I might be doing wrong?

Sample Code:

```
        private async void Connect()
    {
        if (Connected) { return; }

        try
        {
            string Selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
            var DeviceInfoCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(Selector);
            if (DeviceInfoCollection.Count == 0) { return; }
            DeviceInformation DeviceInfo = DeviceInfoCollection[0];

            Port = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(DeviceInfo.Id);
            if (Port == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Port failed to create: " + DeviceInfo.Id);
                Connected = false;
            }

            Port.BaudRate = 19200;
            Port.Parity = SerialParity.Space;
            Port.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
            Port.DataBits = 8;
            Port.ErrorReceived += Port_ErrorReceived;
            Port.PinChanged += Port_PinChanged;

            Connected = true;
            Listen();
        }
        catch (Exception Exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception encountered while trying to connect to serial port: " + Exc.Message);
            Connected = false;
        }
    }

    private async void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Port != null)
            {
                Reader = new DataReader(Port.InputStream);
                while (true)
                {
                    await ReadAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException Exc)
        {
            CloseDevice();
        }
        catch (Exception Exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error encountered while reading from the port: " + Exc.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Reader != null)
            {
                Reader.DetachStream();
                Reader.Dispose();
                Reader = null;
            }

            Connected = false;
        }
    }
    private async Task ReadAsync()
    {
        Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        using (var ChildTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(Token))
        {
            Reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            Task<UInt32> LoadAsyncTask = Reader.LoadAsync(1).AsTask(ChildTokenSource.Token);
            uint BytesRead = await LoadAsyncTask;
            if (BytesRead > 0)
            {
                byte B = Reader.ReadByte(); // Should be getting parity error here
                Debug.WriteLine(B.ToString("X2")); 
                DataQueue.Post(B);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a hardware issue. The serial hat I was using doesn't detect Parity errors. The same code picks of parity errors just fine when ran on a different platform with a different serial card.

Comment: I'm also implementing the gaming machine protocol.
Did you manage to get the wake up bit detected consistently? used any specific serial chip? windows or linux?